# Youtube - How to force 480p video quality in embed link / <iframe>

Tags: iframe, youtube

How to force 480p video quality for iframed Youtube videos?

Sample code:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/FqRgAs0SOpU" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Answer (score 75):

Append the following parameter to the Youtube-URL:

144p: &vq=tiny 
240p: &vq=small 
360p: &vq=medium 
480p: **&vq=large** 
720p: &vq=hd720

For instance:

```
src="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oDOXeO9fAg4"
```

becomes:

```
src="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oDOXeO9fAg4&vq=large"
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me. Only when I try `?rel=0&vq=large` it does.

Comment: Also check if the youtube video provides 360p, 480p, 720p etc. If 480p is missing, setting the parameter will have no effect.

Comment: @pepper_chico: The `?rel=0&vq=large` you need when you use the standard iframe embed, e.g. `<iframe width="560" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/VIDEOID?rel=0&vq=large" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>`

Comment: it works only for embed videos (you cannot use it on youtube site), and you should use `src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/VIDEO-ID"`. `src="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VIDEO-ID"` didn't even show any video (at least if I open my test.html just in web-browser, not from a server). And it won't set for example 1080p if size of iframe window smaller than 1920x1080px (or mb it depends on your monitor)

Comment: This answer only applies when watching videos in the browser, and not via an iframe embed, as per the original question.

Answer (score 6):

You can also use for 1080 hd values:

240p: &vq=small , 360p: &vq=medium , 480p: &vq=large , 720p: &vq=hd720 , **&vq=hd1080**

Answer (score 2):

I found that as of May, 2012, if you set the frame size so that the minimum pixel area (width • height) is above a certain threshold, it bumps the quality up from 360p to 480p, if you're video is at least 640 x 360.

I've discovered that setting a frame size to **780** x 480 for the embed frame triggers the 480p quality, without distorting the video (scaling up). 640 x **585** also works in this manner. I also used the `&hd=1` parameter, but I doubt this has much control if your video is not uploaded in HD (720p or higher).

For instance:

```
<iframe width="780" height="480" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/[VIDEO-ID]?rel=0&fs=1&showinfo=0&autohide=1&hd=1"></iframe>
```

Of course, the drawback is that by setting these static frame dimensions, you will most likely get black bars on the sides or above and below, depending on what you prefer.

If you didn't care about the controls being cut-off, you could go on to use CSS and `overflow: hidden` to crop the black bars out of the frame, providing you know the exact dimensions of the video.

Hope this helps, and hope the Embed method soon gets discrete quality parameters again one day!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [YouTube JavaScript player API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference), which has a feature on its own to set playback quality.

```
player.setPlaybackQuality(suggestedQuality:String):Void
```

> This function sets the suggested video quality for the current video. The function causes the video to reload at its current position in the new quality. If the playback quality does change, it will only change for the video being played. Calling this function does not guarantee that the playback quality will actually change. However, if the playback quality does change, the onPlaybackQualityChange event will fire, and your code should respond to the event rather than the fact that it called the setPlaybackQuality function. [[source]](https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference#Playback_quality)

Comment: I have no direct control of page code. I was hoping I could use just a certain parameter in embed URL... :(

Comment: Unfortunately they removed the &fmt= option which you could use to do this and I have no idea why..

Comment: Oh I didn't know fmt= was removed ! :(

Answer (score 0):

For some updated information on this topic

https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters

**enablejsapi**
Setting the parameter's value to 1 enables the player to be controlled via IFrame Player API calls. The default value is 0, which means that the player cannot be controlled using that API.

...?rel=0&vq=large&enablejsapi=1

Answer (score -2):

You can use the `fmt=` parameter and fill the value based on the following table :

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YouTube#Quality_and_codecs

Ex : your URL would become :

```
http://www.youtube.com/embed/FqRgAs0SOpU?fmt=35
```

Comment: Oh Noooo :( How could they do that ?