# Embed a youtube video choosing quality and problems with safari

Tags: safari, youtube, embed

I've used this code

```
<iframe width="640" height="480" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/....?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

to embed a youtube video.

I would like to automatically set the quality to the max available (which in my case is apparently 480); what happens is:

1) Firefox 12.0: the starting quality is never 480, sometime 360 sometime 240 (yes it changes from time to time)

2) Safari 5.1.4: there is just one option, 360. Why?

I read [Youtube - How to force 480p video quality in embed link / <iframe>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10229114/youtube-how-to-force-480p-video-quality-in-embed-link-iframe) but even if I increase the frame size nothing changes. The javascript method also seems to be not reliable.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding “&ap=%2526fmt%3D18″ and “&ap=%2526fmt%3D22″ to the embed url. I believe D22 is 1280 and D18 is 460?

The syntax is apparently not the same for embedded as it is for the browser's regular url (which is what is given in the answer in your link)

EDIT:
Found the codec information; put the FMT value after the D (ex D18 D22)
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YouTube#Quality_and_codecs

Comment: apparently, as you can see from the URL I posted, the FTM value has been disabled.

Comment: It's possible I'm wrong (very possible, as I've not checked personally), but I read the regular FMT values are not working; however prepending the value with %3D## works. Again, not tested, just suggesting.