# How to force YouTube Lowest Quality via Embed URL Parameter [2016]

Tags: html, iframe, youtube, youtube-api

This question (only similar Q on S/O) was answered in a perplexing haywire back in 2012: [YouTube force 480p embed link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10229114/youtube-how-to-force-480p-video-quality-in-embed-link-iframe)

It briefly covers using `&vq=small` to load 240p, as so:

```
<iframe src="//youtube.com/embed/FqRgAs0SOpU?rel=0&vq=small" width="560" height="315" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

It is said in the answers that `&rel=0` was also required at the time.

**The Problem:** It is also said that if the video isn't available in the chosen quality, it will load the default (usually 720p).

There are also other keywords, such as `&hd=0` and `&fmt=###` to choose the codec & quality.

It is also known that changing the `iframe`'s width and height will tell YT which quality to use.

**Question:** First of all, which parameter (or combination of) is right?

**More specific Question:** How do I tell Youtube, in a URL, to use the *lowest* quality possible, regardless of connection speed, screen size, or any other circumstance?

**Extra:** What is the URL parameter for 144p? [Proof: Screenshot of Youtube App](http://www.cnet.com/how-to/how-to-change-the-video-quality-on-the-youtube-app-for-ios/)

Also, this is Google Dev's YouTube URL parameter reference, [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters)

Thanks for any input.

Answer (score 1):

The parameter `"&afmt=55"` plays a video with `"55 kiloBytes per second"` (very low quality).

Sample:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=qGAwWOfaXTo&afmt=55

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Can you find any documentation on this?